# Performance issue with moving page elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

If your moving page elements with jQuery (eg with append) at what point will you notice a delay due to performance?

Im loading my javascript in a manor that avoids the flash of unstyled content. Due to limitations of the CMS Im using Im moving entire sections of page around in the dom on page load with jQuery. I havnt noticed any delay doing this, but common sense tells me that some users may experience a delay eg on less powerful mobile devices. Are my concerns founded?

Here is an example of a blog post of someone doing something similar: 
http://www.simonbingham.me.uk/index.cfm/main/post/uuid/moving-page-elements-using-jquery-11

Comment: The first optimization rule: 1. Localize issue 2. Fix it. For some reason you've skipped the step one and started solving the issue you don't even sure if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, but Id rather be aware of issues before I create them. Also I cant test on every device that users will be using so I think that the accepted wisdom around best practice would also be useful to know.

Comment: "but Id rather be aware of issues before I create them" --- that's one point. Another point is that if you don't have experience in some particular area (in this case - DOM operations optimisation) there is a chance you either will optimize it wrong, or optimize not the thing that need to be optimized. It was proven million times by even world-wide known developers. Well, anyway, if you think that there is a silver bullet and that you really need to spend (waste?) your time on that - good luck :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind, there are cloud based browsers out there for less powerful devices. So as long as you are running your DOM manipulations in the `ready` function and it takes less than 2 seconds you should be fine. In my experience, browsers tend to be very good at handling DOM changes when you first load the page.